# How to combine files and search the result?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have two sample files as follows:

#### File1

```
item name="NY" block="A" idnum="12345"
item name="NJ" block="B" idnum="123456"
item name="CT" block="C" idnum="1234567"
```

#### File2

```
ID_B|ID_C|NY|4|8198|10|2374|127
ID_C|ID_D|NJ|4|8198|10|2374|127
ID_D|ID_E|CT|4|8198|10|2374|127
```

I would like to be able to generate a file as passing ID as argument and output should look like this

If I am looking for info for `ID_B` then output should be

```
ID_B|ID_C|NY|4|8198|10|2374|127 => "NY" block="A" idnum="12345"
```

If am looking for two `ID_C` and `ID_D` together it should be

```
ID_C|ID_D|NJ|4|8198|10|2374|127 => "NJ" block="B" idnum="123456"
ID_D|ID_E|CT|4|8198|10|2374|127 => "CT" block="C" idnum="1234567"
```

Comment: You want to look for lines based on the first field in file2? Then match the third field in file2 to the name value in file1?

Comment: or is there a one-to-one correspondence in the lines so if the ID you want occurs in line 2 of file2 then you also want line 2 of file1?

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
echo "Please enter the key"
read key
grep "item name=\"$(grep "^${key}|" file2 | cut -d"|" -f3)\"" file1
```

Edit:
I did not make the literal output, just wanted to show that you could grep the fields. A complete solution should look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "Usage $0 id [id2 ..]"
   exit 1
fi

for key in $*; do
   f2=$(grep "^${key}|" file2 )
   f1=$(grep "item name=\"$(echo "^${f2}" | cut -d"|" -f3)\"" file1 )
   echo "${f2} => ${f1#item name=}"
done
```

Comment: @RolfofSaxony I agree, it was only showing how you could start. See edit for a working solution.

Comment: (For the first snippet) Up for the great problem simplification by the creatively used literal interpretation :-)

Answer (score 2):

With bash, join, sort and awk.

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

file1="File1"
file2="File2"

grep -f <(printf "^%s|\n" "$@") <(join -t '|' -1 1 -2 3 <(awk -F'"' '{OFS="|"; print $2,$4,$6}' "$file1" | sort -t '|' -k 1,1) <(sort -t '|' -k 3,3 "$file2") -o 2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8,2.3,1.2,1.3 | awk -F'|' '{ printf "%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s => \"%s\" block=\"%s\" idnum=\"%s\"\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11 }')
```

Example: `script.sh ID_C ID_D`

Output:

```
ID_D|ID_E|CT|4|8198|10|2374|127 => "CT" block="C" idnum="1234567"
ID_C|ID_D|NJ|4|8198|10|2374|127 => "NJ" block="B" idnum="123456"
```

Comment: You might want to sprinkle a few newlines in there.

Answer (score 1):

awk, wrapped in a thin shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
awk -F '[|"]' -v OFS='"' -v keys="$*" '
    BEGIN { 
        n = split(keys, a, " ") 
        for (i=1; i <= n; i++) key[a[i]] = 1
    }
    NR == FNR {
        if ($1 in key) line[$3] = $0
        next
    }
    $2 in line {
        $1 = line[$2] " => "
        print
    }
' file2 file1
```

Then

```
$ sh script.sh ID_B ID_D
ID_B|ID_C|NY|4|8198|10|2374|127 => "NY" block="A" idnum="12345"
ID_D|ID_E|CT|4|8198|10|2374|127 => "CT" block="C" idnum="1234567"
```

Comment: I really like this template where I almost had the solution of my problem however since I don't much knowledge overall codes so I was unable to make it useful. Please help sorting this out.


file2
`ID123|222|company bofa|BOFA|column5|column6`
 ` ID124 |333|company citi|CITI|column5|column6`

file1
`<company name="BOFA" type="DOUBLE" id="4444">`
  `<company name="CITI" type="Int32" id="5555">`

Comment: `
#!/bin/sh

file1="/opt/daily/daily-file"
file2="/opt/weekly/weekly-file"
awk -F '[|"]' -v OFS='"' -v keys="$*" '
    BEGIN {
        n = split(keys, a, " ")
        for (i=1; i <= n; i++) key[a[i]] = 1
    }
    NR == FNR {
        if ($1 in key) line[$5] = $0
        next
    }
    $5 in line {
        $1 = line[$5] " => "
        print
    }
`' $file2 $fil1`

Comment: I really  appreciate for your help with this. Thanks

Comment: looks like your columns don't correspond to what you put in the question. You seem to be using `$5` a lot in your code: why? Think about that question, and what field numbers you should be using instead.

Answer (score 0):

What you want, is very similar to the JOIN in the SQL.

Unfortunately, implementing this in procedural languages like bash, awk or sed, requires dictionaries, or string-indexed string arrays. (And even with them would be it much more complex as a single-line sql query.) None of them supports it, although there are numerous possibilities to emulate it.

In your place I would use perl or python to solve this problem - on these languages would be your goal so simple, that even with the additional learning effort would it be around so effective as a bash workaround.

But you want a bash-awk-sed solution, so this is what I give you now.

Don't use these languages alone, use them integrated. The most simplest thing what you can do in bash, to use the external command `grep`.

For example, an integrated awk/bash core which partially does your the task (I didn't tested it):

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="[_|]"} { print $2 " " $0}' file1|while read l
do
  set $l
  echo $2 $(grep 'block="'$1'"' file2)
done
```

But to understand this code, debug it and extend it, you need to have a big experience in regexps, exact details of escaping, and how is it the fastest to integrate them on both of these languages. On my opinion, if you are learning programming, it is a must-have before you start to learn perl/python, but in everyday work the higher level solutions are better.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write a short bash script that will retrieve the information in a brute-force manner:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -z "$1" -o -z "$2" -o -z "$3" ] && {
    printf "error: insufficient input. Usage: %s file1 file2 query\n" ${0##*/}
    exit 1
}

file1="$1"
file2="$2"
query="$3"

## line from file1
f1=$(grep "$query" "$file1")
[ -z "$f1" ] && {
    printf "error: '%s' not found in '%s'\n." "$query" "$file1"
    exit 1
}

## line from file2
f2=$(grep $(awk -F '|' '{ print $3 }' <<<$f1) "$file2")
[ -z "$f1" ] && {
    printf "error: no related row found in '%s'\n." "$file2"
    exit 1
}

printf "%s => %s\n" "$f1" "$f2"
```

**Examples**

```
$ bash joinfiles.sh join1.txt join2.txt ID_B
ID_B|ID_C|NY|4|8198|10|2374|127 => item name="NY" block="A" idnum="12345"

$ bash joinfiles.sh join1.txt join2.txt ID_E
ID_D|ID_E|CT|4|8198|10|2374|127 => item name="CT" block="C" idnum="1234567"

$ bash joinfiles.sh join1.txt join2.txt ID_F
error: 'ID_F' not found in 'join1.txt'
```

**Processing Multiple Input Tags**

With small adjustments, you can easily process as many tags as you desire. Below, the code will match all of the tags provided as arguments 3 and beyond. If you want to provide more than a half-dozed tags at a time, then you should adjust the script to read tags from `stdin` instead of taking them as arguments. Also note, the code matches the tag in the first field of the first file. If you want to match tags in all fields in file one, then `f1` will become an array and the remaining part of the code with operate on each element in `f1`. Let me know what you are thinking. Here is the example for multiple input tags as arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -z "$1" -o -z "$2" -o -z "$3" ] && {
    printf "error: insufficient input. Usage: %s file1 file2 query\n" ${0##*/}
    exit 1
}

[ -f "$1" -a -f "$2" ] || {
    printf "error: file not found.  '%s' or '%s'\n" "$1" "$2"
    exit 1
}

file1="$1"
file2="$2"

for i in "${@:3}"; do

    query="$i"

    ## line from file1
    f1=$(grep "^$query" "$file1")
    [ -z "$f1" ] && {
        printf "error: '%s' not found in '%s'\n." "$query" "$file1"
        exit 1
    }

    ## line from file2
    f2=$(grep $(awk -F '|' '{ print $3 }' <<<$f1) "$file2")
    [ -z "$f1" ] && {
        printf "error: no related row found in '%s'\n." "$file2"
        exit 1
    }

    printf "%s => %s\n" "$f1" "$f2"

done
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ bash joinfiles2.sh join1.txt join2.txt ID_B ID_D ID_F
ID_B|ID_C|NY|4|8198|10|2374|127 => item name="NY" block="A" idnum="12345"
ID_D|ID_E|CT|4|8198|10|2374|127 => item name="CT" block="C" idnum="1234567"
error: 'ID_F' not found in 'join1.txt'
```

Comment: OP wants to be able to provide more than one ID to query.

Comment: Thanks, added processing multiple tags as arguments, noted if processing greater than 6 tags at a time, then reading from `stdin` would be wise.

Comment: Thanks so much for all of your feedbacks. I will give it a try to see how it comes down. Thanks again.